# I have Youngs Elderberry kit

Tags: fermentation, kits, primary

I am on day 3 and instructions state "top up 4.54 litres tepid water". Does this mean top up TO 4.54 litres? Should I leave space in the demijohn and how much space? It's still got 7 to 20 days to ferment yet! Terrible instructions as very vague and badly worded.

Thanks

JY
Newbie!

---

I did that and it bubbled up into the airlock! I had to take some liquid out again!  Maybe I've just got a lively must going!

I've topped it up again now and it's still quite lively!  Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I believe it should say "top up to 4.54L with tap water..."

I base myself on existing instructions for another Youngs kit... [Youngs wine kit instruction](https://www.youngsgroup.co.uk/images/instructions/Wine%20Buddy%201g.pdf)

The ideal situation is to have very little space left (perhaps 2 inches depending on the size of the container) to avoid oxydation.